# Same function name different parameter type

Tags: php

Can i have a function like this:

```
public function user_to(String $user = null){
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
```

And another one like this

```
public function user_to(Array $user = null){
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
```

without having any problem at all? i mean, i want the first to be called only when the parameter is an string and the second one when it is an array.

I know i can do it with only one function and doing a `gettype()` to know if its an array or a string but i want to have different functions

Comment: Did you try it? It seems like something you could test for yourself in only a few minutes

Comment: Im doing it right know, just need you opinions while im on it.

Comment: Maybe a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165467/why-php-doesnt-support-function-overloading might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't allow for multiple functions with the same name. So you should instead of defining a separate function with the same name, but different variable-type, you can check for that inside the function.

```
public function user_to($user = null){
    if (is_array($user) || is_string($user)) {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    } else {
        /* Do whatever; for example throw an exception or return false */
    }
}
```

Attempting to redeclare a function that already exists in PHP gives a fatal error. From the manual,

> PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

In the upcoming PHP 8, you can define multiple types in your typehinting, or "union types" ([reference](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2)).

So you can require the argument to be of either array or string, or nullable (as that is the default value).

```php
public function user_to(array|string|null $user = null) {
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
```

This will however throw a fatal error if you insert a different type, something along the lines of..

> Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to user_to() must be of the type string, object given